# What does shortmess+=A do about the swp file?

Tags: swap-file

`:h shortmess` says:

> ```
> A    don't give the "ATTENTION" message when an existing swap file is found.
> ```

But then what does Vim do about the existing swap file? Some people say it's bad to use that option, why so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `A` option Vim will just forget about swap at all.

You'll stop getting messages about a swap file being found and if you're editing the same file in different terminals at the same time, it's your problem <3

---

**EDIT:**

What I mean is that Vim will not care about the swap file

Let's put a example:

You open `main.c` in terminal A, and you write something in it. 
You save it with `:w` without closing vim.

Then you open `main.c` in terminal B and edit it again, 
You save it with `wq`.
(normally at this point the swap attention text would appear, but you have disabled it)

Finally, in Terminal A, you edit it and save it  with `wq`, exiting vim now.
Then a prompt will appear telling you that the file has been changed since you opened it, and if you really want to save it or no.

If you say to save it anyway, result is that you'll lose all the stuff you wrote in the file in Terminal B, because Terminal A never "saw" it.

Comment: With `set noswapfile` Vim "will just forget about swap files at all". With `shortmess+=A` swapfiles are still created and modified, and I want to know how Vim handles conflicts if it doesn't ask you what to do, and why that would be a bad idea as long as you know what it's doing.

Comment: I tried to explain it better, check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

According to [`:help swap-file`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html#swap-file):

> - If this file already exists (e.g., when you are recovering from a crash) a   warning is given and another extension is used, ".swo",
>     ".swn", etc.
> - An existing file will never be overwritten.
> - The swap file is deleted as soon as Vim stops editing the file.

So if you realise that you need to recover from a swap file, even without the warning, then you can still manually [recover it](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html#recovery) at any time unless you explicitly deleted it.

I've decided to use the `shortmess=A` option because:

- Nearly all of the swap file warnings are false positives (e.g. my PC crashed, but the file was already saved because I have set Vim to [auto save when the window focus changes](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Auto_save_files_when_focus_is_lost)).
- If there is ever a genuine loss of data, then I will probably notice the problem without the warning, and be able to manually recover the data from the swap file.